# How to type hint a function that returns a map() object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have the following function (inside of the class shown as well) in my code:

```py
class Range:
    def __init__(self, string_representation: str):
        self.string_representation = string_representation

    # ...

    def get_start_and_end_numbers(self):    # <--- This one
        return map(int, self.string_representation.split('-'))

    # ...
```

As you can see, what it does is: Given a `string_representation` like `'1-4'`, the function returns a `map()` object that yields the integer values `1` and `4`.

So I guessed that this should be enough:

```
def get_start_and_end_numbers(self) -> map:
    return map(int, self.string_representation.split('-'))
```

But then I would not be type hinting the "*content*" of the map, i.e: the integers.

So, how should I type hint that returned `map()` object?

Comment: `Iterator[int]`? You can always look at [the typeshed definitions](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/5bc6726e3ff194c00e970c89cb4b1f8f345f7fa6/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L997-L1032), or put something obviously wrong (but actually a *type*, `map` isn't) and see what the error says!

Comment: Use `Iterator[int]`

Comment: Thank you! @jonrsharpe Why `map` is not a type but, for example, `int` is?

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga if any of you add an answer, I will accept it. Future visitors might benefit from that.

Comment: Because `int` is a type but `map` is a function?

Comment: Hmmm but if I do `type(map)` it says that it is a `type` instead of a function. @jonrsharpe

Comment: @jonrsharpe no, `map` is a type, but I don't think it supports generic annotations.

Comment: From the MyPy's perspective, *"Function "builtins.map" is not valid as a type"* - that's consistent with the type shed definitions. But yes, it seems it is a type in CPython itself.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again for the insightful answer @jonrsharpe

Comment: I'm out of votes, but here's a possible dupe that covers this case specifically and how to find out in general: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58465482/3001761

Comment: Oh great! Thank you. That question (which I couldn't find by myself, otherwise I wouldn't had made this one) covers my case indeed, so I'm deleting this one. @jonrsharpe

Comment: I think it should be closed as duplicate but remain as a signpost, don’t delete it. Not all dupes are bad; some make the canonical content easier to find for the next person, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/.